# Background Service or Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, service, android-broadcastreceiver

It is an app locker application that I am working on. It locks all the apps in the android phone. What I want to do is that when a locked app is run in the android, my application should stop the app and display a password or pattern screen, if pattern is correct then it should run the app otherwise disable it. So, I wanted to ask that should I use background service to do that or should I use broadcast receiver? I don't know if the app sends broadcast when it runs for the first time? And if I use the background service, will it run when the android is restarted? I mean without running the application again? Please help me so that I can understand it well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background service is probably the better choice for this type of requirements. And yes, you can make the background service start when the phone is restarted by using `BroadcastReceiver`. This is how:

Make sure to have this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Then in `application` tag, have this receiver:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then finally, the `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class MyBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
            context.startService(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

This way, your service will start each time device reboots.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I really appreciate that. I just wanted to ask one more thing that if you can help me find out how to get the name of the currently running application? Because i couldn't find any good solution.

Comment: use this lib  to get current running application : https://github.com/ricvalerio/foregroundappchecker

Comment: Thank you @MayVaBao

Comment: @MayVaBao How to use this library? There are a lot of errors when i loaded this into android studio. But i somehow managed to get the code out of it and it always returns null in Foreground Service.

Answer (score 0):

Use need add android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS to manifest and if your android version is 5.0 and above run this code to request usage stat permission :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
 startActivity(intent);
```